# How to use if condition in a select query?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, select

I have a start date and end date column in my table and I get a start date and end date as input. I need to set START date as TBL.StartDate if it is after INPUT Start Date and I need to set END date as TBL.EndDate if it is before INPUT End Date. Finally count the days between START and END.

I'm trying to use if statement but I fail when I try to use if in select query.

I'm not sure if this is a correct way of solving this problem.

```
Declare @Start Date;
Declare @End Date;
Declare @INPUT_StartDate Date;
Declare @INPUT_EndDate Date;

set @INPUT_StartDate = '2019-01-01'; --user input
set @INPUT_EndDate = '2019-04-20'; --user input

select 
TBL.StartDate, 
TBL.EndDate, 
@INPUT_StartDate, 
@INPUT_EndDate,
if(TBL.StartDate < INPUT_StartDate) set @Start = TBL.STARTDate;
else set @Start = INPUT_StartDate;
if(TBL.EndDate < INPUT_EndDate) set @End = INPUT_EndDate;
else set @End = TBL.EndDate;
@DateDiff(day, @Start, @End) as COUNT
 from TBL
```

I'm expecting that this comparison happens, but i guess i'm using if statement in between select query is not allowed?

Actual results are quite a few syntax errors near if.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] is this? [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: Yes. It's SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure of case statement which is same as if but used in case statement. if you want to use if in select list(there is IIF if your sql server is 2012+). If is mostly used in conditional logic.

I removed @start and @end date variable which might not be required based on the logic you are using.

```
select  '2019-03-20' as startdate, '2019-04-20' as ENddate into #temp union all 
select  '2018-02-01' as startdate, '2019-03-20' as ENddate   



    Declare @Start Date;
Declare @End Date;
Declare @INPUT_StartDate Date;
Declare @INPUT_EndDate Date;

set @INPUT_StartDate = '2019-01-01'; --user input
set @INPUT_EndDate = '2019-04-20'; --user input

select 
TBL.StartDate, 
TBL.EndDate, 
@INPUT_StartDate INPUT_StartDate, 
@INPUT_EndDate INPUT_EndDate,

datediff(day, case when tbl.StartDate < @INPUT_StartDate  then   TBL.STARTDate 
else   @INPUT_StartDate end, 
case when TBL.EndDate < @INPUT_EndDate  then @INPUT_EndDate
else  TBL.EndDate end) date_diff  

 from #temp tbl
```

Output:

```
Startdate   Enddate     Input_startdate    input_enddate   date_diff
2019-03-20  2019-04-20  2019-01-01         2019-04-20      109
2018-02-01  2019-03-20  2019-01-01          2019-04-20     443
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have `least()` or `greatest()`.  And SQL Server doesn't allow you to mix selecting columns with setting variables.

I recommend setting the values in a "subquery", in this case, using `apply`:

```
select t.StartDate,  t.EndDate, 
       @INPUT_StartDate, @INPUT_EndDate,
       DateDiff(day, v.dateStart, v.dateEnd) as num_days
from tbl t cross apply
     (values (case when t.StartDate < @INPUT_StartDate
                   then t.STARTDate
                   else @INPUT_StartDate
              end,
              case when t.EndDate < @INPUT_EndDate
                   then INPUT_EndDate
                   else @TBL.EndDate
              end
             )
     ) v(startDate, endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @StartDate datetime,@msg varchar(100),@Diff int
declare @EndDate datetime
declare @TodayDate datetime
set @StartDate = '2019-04-23'    ---Define Start Date-----
set @EndDate = '2019-04-30'      ---Define End Date-----
set @TodayDate = GETDATE()
            if(@StartDate < @TodayDate)
            begin
            set @msg = 'Date is Smaller than today date'
            select @msg
            end
                    else
                    begin
                    select @Diff = DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate)
                    set @msg = @Diff
                    select @msg as Days_Differance
            end
```

[image]